# Flutter Getx BottomNavigation with GetPage

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-getx, flutter-bottomnavigation

I'm using getx navigation with page binding - for example:

```
GetPage(
  name: Routes.pageone,
  page: () => PageOne(),
  binding: PageOneBinding(),
),
GetPage(
  name: Routes.pagetwo,
  page: () => PageTwo(),
  binding: PageTwoBinding(),
),
GetPage(
  name: Routes.pagethree,
  page: () => PageThree(),
  binding: PageThreeBinding(),
),
```

And each page would have its own controller and binding.

Usually to navigate to other page I would use
`Get.toNamed(Routes.pageone)` like this using routing.

However, when I use tabbar/bottom navigation bar, I want to **keep the scaffold's app bar and bottom navigation bar and just switch the content using getx**. The only method I was able to do was having scaffold for all the pages and reload all the content whenever I click on each tabs, which is inefficient and would load unnecessary widgets everytime i switch to pages (appbar, title, bottom nav bar, etc.).

The usual method of loading tab contents like

```
List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
  PageOne(),
  PageTwo(),
  PageThree(),
];
```

isn't using getx GetPage() with binding, and would load all the controllers of all pages. I can't find proper reference of using GetPage() and bottom nav bar.

For example, my navigation stack when loading app would be `/main/pageone` and would stack each page into my stack whenever I switch tab. (`/main/pageone` click tab3-> `/main/pageone/pagethree`) And when I press each tab the controller for that tab would be loaded and previous controller would be deleted.

I am unsure what I should put into the `body` of my scaffold, which would receive widget but using GetPage with binding confuses me.

Here is the page file code for my app

```
class MyPage extends GetView<MyPageController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Title'),
      ),
      body: 
      /// this is the part where I'm lost on what to put
      SafeArea(
        child: IndexedStack(
          index: controller.curTabIdx.value,
          children: [
            controller.mainContent.value,
          ],
        )
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (value) => controller.onNavTap(value),
        currentIndex: controller.curTabIdx.value,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Page 1'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Page 2'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Page 3'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you need controller code as well, I can insert it as well.

Comment: https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/680#issuecomment-703881801

Comment: Hello @Jaebi have you got any luck ?

Answer (score -2):

I think you can solve this problem adding Obx() to observe your var so can respond as you wish.

In the third pillar you can see they talking about [state management using Obx()](https://pub.dev/packages/get#obxvalue):

"And in the UI, when you want to show that value and update the screen whenever the values changes, simply do this:"

```
Obx(() => Text("${controller.name}"));
```

---

```
class MyPage extends GetView<MyPageController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Title'),
      ),
      body: 
      Obx(
         () {
          return SafeArea(
            child: IndexedStack(
              index: controller.curTabIdx.value,
              children: [
                controller.mainContent.value,
              ],
            )
          );
        }
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (value) => controller.onNavTap(value),
        currentIndex: controller.curTabIdx.value,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Page 1'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Page 2'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'Page 3'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```